# Int variable when set to zero behaves odd

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code and when I expected it not to go in the if block, it did. Inherited code, so I am choosing to ignore original programmers idea of mixing data types - so trying really hard to set aside code quality question.

```
Declare @computedValue int
set @computedValue = 0

if(@computedValue = '')
Begin
    select 'its empty'
End
```

Why would this print "its empty" when I set the value of `@computedValue` to zero which clearly is not ''?

The odd thing is, if I set it to some number other than zero, it does not go inside the if.

The actual assignment of `@computedValue`:

```
select @computedValue = case when Block_Value is null or Block_Value = '' then null else Block_Value end
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @DaleK Yes, I do. The last paragraph of [Converting Character Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#_character) starts with: "When an empty string get converted to an `int`, its value becomes `0`." (Okay, that took less than five minutes of scrounging, but _now_ I now where it is Officially Stated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`select convert(int, '')` returns `0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#_character) - its one of the many automatic type conversions carried out by SQL Server. Here is how you can handle your situation:

```
declare @Block_Value varchar(12) = '';

declare @computedValue int;
set @computedValue = 0;

-- select @computedValue = case when Block_Value is null or Block_Value = '' then null else Block_Value end
select @computedValue = nullif(@Block_Value,'');

if @computedValue is null
begin
    select 'its empty';
end;
```

Further, [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) explains why the empty string is converted to an `int` in your compare (rather than the other way around).